# SQL Query to return matches

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this query below:

```
SELECT ied.[Reference]
    ,Count(*) AS 'Hits'
FROM dbo.ItemExportDefinition ied WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN dbo.[Hits] WH WITH (NOLOCK) ON ied.[Reference] COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('&', WH.QUERY, 0) = 0
            THEN SUBSTRING(WH.QUERY, 4, 30)
        WHEN CHARINDEX('&', WH.QUERY, 0) > 0
            THEN SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(WH.QUERY, 0, CHARINDEX('&', WH.QUERY)), 4, 100)
        ELSE WH.QUERY
        END
GROUP BY ied.[Guide Web Reference]
ORDER BY Hits DESC
```

It returns these values:

```
ESC7730AE5  273697
ES4904A3EA  152392
ES0C69E6B9  11829
ES2413515E  5653
ESBA042518  1144
ES193DFEC8  1067
ESBF086D49  77
ES0AA87194  25
ESIXVY6881  9
ESE77AEF31  4
ES4087624D  3
ESF8BD9328  2
```

What I want is that I want to get the results where the count is 0. So for example it look like this:

```
ESC7730AE5  273697
ES4904A3EA  152392
ES0C69E6B9  11829
ES2413515E  5653
ESBA042518  1144
ES193DFEC8  1067
ESBF086D49  77
ES0AA87194  25
ESIXVY6881  9
ESE77AEF31  4
ES4087624D  3
ESF8BD9328  2
ESF8BD9328A 0
ESF8BD932832    0
ESF8BD932888    0
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is there the last three values in the `ItemExportDefinition` table?

Comment: No, The last three values is something i typed in to show what i want.

Comment: So, where the sql server will got this values to add to your result?

Comment: What do you mean? Im sorry.

Comment: I mean, if there are no such data in table how sql server can show it. It show data with corresponding data count in the table `Hits`.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. What I Intend to do is that I want to show matches and if there is no matches then it should show 0 as hits. 
I know that Count(*) is not the right solution here because it shows counts > 0. But I showed what I came up with so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
Count(*) AS 'Hits'
```

on

```
Count(WH.QUERY) AS 'Hits'
```

Count(*) counts all rows, Count() - count amount of values in (except NULLs)

Comment: Perfect! How Come i've missed that! Makes totally sense that count(*) counts the rows and count(Column) returns amount. Thank you very much!